# Can Einstein's action at a distance be action into the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, causality, wavefunction-collapse

This youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k) is about how it is not measurable or of any consequence what the one way speed of light is, only that a two way trip has an average speed of $c$. An example is moving instantaneously in one direction and $c/2$ on the return trip. He mentions papers for models where $c$ is not uniform.

Consider Einstein's instantaneous action at a distance between two entangled particles $A, B$. Say the light is instantaneous from $A$ to $B$ and at speed $c/2$ from $B$ to $A$.

From this perspective, if the wave state of $A$ collapses, $B$ collapses in the past, because in the case where the one way speed of light was $c$, $B$ collapsed before it saw the light of $A$ collapsing.

Similarly if the wave state of $B$ is collapses, $A$ collapses in the future.

My question is if this valid and if so if anyone has talked about it?

Answer (score 1):

How come that wouldn't have any measurable consequences? For example, looking at the night sky, you would see stars at different ages in one direction but all the same age in another direction. That would definitely be measureable as an asymmetry, so lack of such asymmetry in measurements would need to be explained.

What is more interesting question is whether light travels discontinuously in 4-dimensional space-time. I mean, light could always "jump" from its point of emission to its point of absorption in a sense of *action at distance* as described by Einstein, but in such way that the time coordinate difference depends on the spatial  distance between the two points, so that all observers observe speed of light in vacuum to be c.

Of course that hypothesis is also undermined by measurement, since gravitational field between the two points impacts also light, so somehow if light does discrete jumps, then it remains to be explained how gravitational field between the point of emission and point of absorption impacts it.

In summary, there doesn't seem to be any discrepancy between measurement and the Eistein's theory of relativity. Adding vague hypothesis about the nature of light cannot change that - if it was true that no measurement can distinguish the cases then there wouldn't be any consequences for such hypothesis. But it's much more likely that there is an error in such assumptions.

Comment: So the video is wrong?

Comment: I think they are considering their hypothesis as possible based on lack of evidence to contrary. But it's not quite that hard to find measurements that could settle that issue. What they think is that there are no assumption that can be made about remote locations in the universe except by sending light there and observing it bounce through a mirror or some other setup they control. But we can observe light we receive from faraway stars and compare it with light we receive from other directions. It would be remarkable to find asymmetry at global scale from such measurements.